# SAP Crystal Report Cannot edit Command

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

Please help me how to edit command in SAP Crystal report.
When I open Database Expert and rigt click the Command, its show Rename and Properties, not show Edit Command or View Command.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a command, it is a database object. It seems there is a semicolon at the end of the name so I would say it is a stored procedure.

You will have to edit the object in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Could you mind tell me where i can edit the store procedure?
Sorry I'm new bie on this.

Comment: You have to go to the SQL Server management studio. There, you expand your database, then Programmability-StoredProcedures-MIS_REPORTPO-right click modify.